# Why I am not able to entry data into sqlite database using JDBC java?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to make a ledger (to keep records of sales). I am using sqlite and netbeans.
The problem is that my `INSERT` query is not adding data to the database and the **console is also not showing any error**.
The program consists of 2 files `ledger.java` and `ledgerGUI.java`.
`ledger.java` contains the function definitions to carry out sql queries. These functions are called in `ledgerGUI.java` to add data from `JTextField`.

**Part of the code of ledger.java**

```
  package ledger;
  import java.sql.*;

  public class Ledger  {
  public Connection c = null;
  public Statement stmt = null;

  private String name_db = "";
  private String tm_db = "";
  private String item_db = "";
  private int quantity_db = 0;
  private int price_db = 0;   

// Connecting to the database.
public void connectDb(){        
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Ledger.db");

    } 
    catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e ){        
    }    
}

// Query
public void insertToDb(String name_entry, String tmark_entry, String item_entry, int quantity_entry, int price_entry){
    name_db = name_entry;
    tm_db = tmark_entry;
    item_db = item_entry;
    quantity_db = quantity_entry;
    price_db = price_entry;

    try{
        connectDb();
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO ledger_table (Name, Trade Mark, Item, Quantity, Price) VALUES (name_db, tm_db, item_db, quantity_db, price_db)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);            
        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();           

    }
    catch(Exception e){            
    }             
}
```

**Part of the code of ledgerGui.java**

```
 private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   Ledger lg = new Ledger();
   String name = tf_name.getText();
   String tmark = tf_tmark.getText();
   String item = tf_item.getText();
   int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tf_quantity.getText());
   int price = Integer.parseInt(tf_price.getText());
   try{
       lg.insertToDb(name, tmark.toUpperCase(), item, quantity, price);
   }
         catch(Exception e){      
    }
   tf_item.setText("");
   tf_quantity.setText("");
   tf_price.setText("");
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the program will know that you are referring to variables in your query and not actual values? **INSERT INTO ledger_table (Name, Trade Mark, Item, Quantity, Price) VALUES (name_db, tm_db, item_db, quantity_db, price_db)**. When you state what the values are here, you and I both know you are referring to variable names, but how does the program know that?

Comment: Use a preparred statement instead.

Comment: You can do it that way.  A preparredStatment would be easier and it helps to guard against sql injections. Take a look at how to use them.

Comment: Not Working this way **"INSERT INTO ledger_table (Name, Trade Mark, Item, Quantity, Price) VALUES ("+name_db+", "+tm_db+", "+item_db+", "+quantity_db+", "+price_db+")";**

Comment: Again, please check out how to use a prepared statement. Also, you can't have a column name with a space in it w/o having []'s around it, so Trade Mark should be labeled [Trade Mark]

Comment: Thanks sir ! You saved me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PreparedStatement`, something like this:

```
// Query
public void insertToDb(String name_entry, String tmark_entry, String item_entry, int quantity_entry, int price_entry){
    name_db = name_entry;
    tm_db = tmark_entry;
    item_db = item_entry;
    quantity_db = quantity_entry;
    price_db = price_entry;
try{
    connectDb();
    String query =
        "INSERT INTO ledger_table (Name, Trade Mark, Item, Quantity, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";        
    PreparedStatement statement = c.prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setString(1, name_db);
    statement.setString(2, tm_db);
    statement.setString(3, item_db);
    statement.setInt(4, quantity_db);
    statement.setInt(5, price_db);
    statement.executeUpdate();            
    c.commit();
    c.close();           

}
catch(Exception e){            
}             
}
```

Are you sure that `Trade Mark` has a spaces separator on the table of database...

```
INSERT INTO ledger_table (Name, Trade Mark, Item, Quantity, Price)...
```

Comment: [Trade Mark]  I've fixed that and thank you i'll give it a shot !